# Implement Autocomplete using typeahead.js +Searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, elasticsearch, jquery-autocomplete, searchkick

I am trying to implement autocomplete in my ruby on rails application with elasticsearch. I followed the example in the following link

https://shellycloud.com/blog/2013/10/adding-search-and-autocomplete-to-a-rails-app-with-elasticsearch

It includes html.slim files however when I try to do it with my controller and view files there is nothing happening in the back end. I don't see jQuery running.

My code is as follows.

`app/models/result.rb`:

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick autocomplete: ['univ_name']
end
```

`app/controllers/results_controller.rb` includes the following method

```
class ResultsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:query].present?
      @results = Result.search(params[:query], page: params[:page])
    else
      @results = Result.all.page params[:page]
    end
  end

  def autocomplete
    render json: Book.search(params[:query], autocomplete: true, limit: 10).map(&:title)
  end
end
```

`app/views/index.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_tag results_path, class: "form-inline", method: :get do %>
  <div class="input-group input-group-lg" >
    <%if params[:query].present? %>
      <div class="input-group-btn">
    <%end%>
    <%= link_to "clear", results_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
  </div>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: "form-control", id: "result_search", autocomplete: "off" %>
  <div class=input-group-btn">
    <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

`app/assets/javascripts/results.js.coffee`

```
$ ->
  $('#result_search').typeahead
    name: "result"
    remote: "/results/autocomplete?query=%QUERY"
```

I also included

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"%>
<%= javascript_include_tag "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.9.3/ typeahead.min.js" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "typeahead"%>
```

I have no clue where i am going wrong. Can anyone help me with this?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I added some formatting to your question, but the hierarchy of your view confuses me, is something missing? Seems like the `div`s don’t all match. Also, your Coffeescript was indented incorrectly, but I assume that was a transcription error rather than your actual code? You say you don’t see any request from jQuery, but you haven’t shown yourself including jQuery. Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: @BuckDoyle I get Empty string passed to getElementById() error.

As mentioned in the question I am trying to implement the working example as in the link I posted in my question. I included whatever was explained. However, nothing seems to work

Comment: Is jQuery included? What happens if you run `jQuery` in the console?

Comment: @BuckDoyle I used 
http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js 

Console looks fine except jquery.js shows empty string passed to getElementByID() error

and

Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: Do you mean that there’s an error in the jQuery code? I can’t understand what you mean by “jquery.js shows”.

Comment: What browser are you testing in?

Comment: @BuckDoyle I used firebug to lookup for errors in my page it shows those errors

Comment: What line does the error happen on? What happens on that line? In the stacktrace, what line of your code triggers the error?

Comment: on line 3261: 
src.getPreventDefault && src.getPreventDefault() ) ? returnTrue : returnFalse;

Comment: in your results controller you have Book.search, shouldnt it be Result.search?